# accessing a value from a data structure

Tags: clojure

a is a data structure that stores:

```
                                    []
                                    []
                                    []
                                    (0 2)
```

I want to access last value that is (0 2),how can I do that?

Comment: Do you want the "last" element or the 4th one? Please provide a complete example of what you tried and how it failed, so we can improve on it.

Comment: I needed the (0 2) value to modify it,Now its solved,as I used count function logic..

Comment: If you have a solution, that fixed your problem, it's encouraged to write your own answer on SO; so others can learn from it.

Comment: Actually,according to the structure I was getting,I checked a condition of (if (not= (count a) 0)) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with `get`:

```
(def data [[]
           []
           []
           '(0 2)])

data => [[] [] [] (0 2)]
(get data 3) => (0 2)
```

but it is generally easier if you use square brackets to create a vector instead of a list.  That way, you don't need quoting anywhere:

```
(def data2 [[]
            []
            []
            [0 2]])

data2 => [[] [] [] [0 2]]
(get data2 3) => [0 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But data structure a has same structure.It is not enclosed as you have defined it in data

Comment: Please update your question with the exact code you have.